# Create a Docker Container using VirtualBox on Windows for Kubernetes

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, kubernetes, minikube

I'm starting to experiment with Kubernetes on my Windows 10 dev machine.  I've got minikube running on my machine, with some "canned" test services, so it looks like Kubernetes is working properly.

Now I'm trying to create my first service by following this: http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/

The problem is I can't build the docker image.  I get an error that basically says docker isn't running.  I've installed the docker toolkit, and I've looked at docker for windows, but it needs hyper-v which doesn't work with Kubernetes (it requires VirtualBox).  So is there any way I can get docker running on windows using VirtualBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the docker client on your host windows machine, you can run

`minikube docker-env --shell powershell`

That will point the docker client on your host to the docker daemon inside the minikube VM.